# Is a Debian Testing package safety comparable to Ubuntu “Stable”

Tags: ubuntu, debian, package-management, packages

I've noticed that Ubuntu has newer packages, and I wondered if it has more support or they are less cautious. Turns out it's the latter:

> "Ubuntu packages are based on packages from Debian's unstable branch,
> which are synchronized every six months." *

You might already know Debian packages are: Stable > Testing > Unstable. And for a package to have Testing status needs to receive 0 Bugs last 10 days straight.

So I have two questions, is Ubuntu on purpose a little bit like a *guinea pig* for Debian?

And, how does the safety and stability compare from a Debian package in Testing (Installed on Debian Stable) versus a the standard Ubuntu package.

[*Quote Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu#History)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a slight difference though, Debian focuses on stability, and their end goal is to release a new stable branch every so often. As such, testing doesn't get security fixes quite as fast as stable, and sometimes things break and doesn't get fixed until they are fixed upstream in Sid (unstable).

Ubuntu on the other hand rolls a lot of the packages into a release, and then supports that release for a set period of time, with regular updates and security fixes.

So, even though Ubuntu stable is based on Debian's unstable, it's not as unstable as Debian's testing, since Ubuntu stable is a release, while Debian testing is just that, a testing repository for the next stable branch.

This all boils down to the mission of the different distributions. Debian arguably has created and keeps creating one of the most stable Linux distributions available, which makes it ideal for servers where you don't have as much software installed compared to a desktop machine, and you really care about everything not breaking. This comes at the cost of not getting the latest versions of packages, as it takes time to ensure the level of stability that Debian requires.

Ubuntu on the other hand has created a modern distribution that's more suited to Desktop environments, where you need the latest versions of packages to support more diverse hardware. Then they also have the LTS versions that are more suited for servers for the above reasons, more stability.